# AWS s3Client->copyObject succeeds but the copied object loses is garbled

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

Please assist.
I am successfully uploading objects to S3 using the following code snippet:

```
    // Send a PutObject request and get the result object.
    $result = $this->s3EncryptionClient->putObject([
        '@MaterialsProvider' => $this->materialsProvider,
        '@CipherOptions' => $this->cipherOptions,
        'Bucket' => $this->s3BucketName,
        'Key'    => $key,
        'ContentType' => $mimeType,
        'ContentLength' => filesize($filePath),
        'ContentDisposition' => "attachment; filename='" . $fileName . "'",
        'Body' => fopen($filePath ,'r')
    ]);
```

And I can successfully download the object using the following snippet:

```
    // Download the contents of the object.
    $result = $this->s3EncryptionClient->getObject([
        '@MaterialsProvider' => $this->materialsProvider,
        '@CipherOptions' => $this->cipherOptions,
        'Bucket' => $this->s3BucketName,
        'Key'    => $key 
    ]);
```

The problem comes in when i try copy the object using the following code snippet:

```
    $result = $this->s3Client->CopyObject([
        'Bucket' => $this->s3BucketName,
        'CopySource' => $CopySource,
        'Key' => $dstKey,
    ]);
```

The object seems to be copied incorrectly and when i try download the new object using the download code i pasted earlier in this post, The object is not found and an AWSException

> resulted in a `404 Not Found` response

Any idea how I can resolve the issue?

Comment: What is inside `$CopySource` and `$dstKey`?

Comment: It changes all the time but basically created as follows:

Comment: $CopySource = urlencode("/".$this->s3BucketName."/".$srcKey);
and the $dstKey is just the key of the destination. So for example if the $srcKey is MySource then $CopySource is %2FBucketName%2FMySource and if $dstKey is MyDest then that is its value at time of function call @Justinas